# Applying style to all the child elements within an element

Tags: css

i have an html as below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            p{font-size:14pt;color:red;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <p> this is a p without class defined</p>
        </div>
            <div class = "temp">
            <p> this is a p tag in another div</p>
        </div>
        <div class = "test">
            <p> this is a Original Mail</p>
            <p class="hello"> this is a p tag </p>
            <p> this is a p without class defined</p>
            <div> this is a div tag 
                <p> this is a p tag within the div</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

i want to apply the style to all p Tags within the div with class test.

i tried putting like div.test > p{font-size:14pt;color:red;}
but then the style is not getting applied to the p tag within the child div of div with class name test.
please help me to sort out this.

Answer (score 1):

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8K2yL/

The selector you want is:

```
div.test p {
    font-size:14pt;
    color:red;
}
```

This will select all `p` tags that are anywhere inside a `div.test` tag.

The selector `div.test > p` will only select `p` tags that are DIRECT children of `div.test`.

Answer (score 1):

Specifying the tag name right after the class name selects all the matching tags found inside the class.

```
.test p{
    font-size:14pt;
    color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `>` selector selects direct decendants. Therefore children of children will be ignored.

Change to this:

```
div.test p {
    font-size:14pt;color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do like below

```
 div.test p{
         font-size:14pt;
       color:red;
       }
```

Fiddle for you [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/XmKrm/152/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
  div.test p{
    font-size: 14pt;
    color:     red;
  }
</style>
```